# Events throw error in PixiJs version 7.2.0 after following the example

Tags: vue.js, pixi.js

I am trying out PixiJs for the first time and when I was trying out the dragging example (https://pixijs.io/examples/#/events/dragging.js) I get a bunch of errors refering to the events:
[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFR0L.png)

I am testing it out in a Vue 3 project, as that is where I want to implement it eventually.

I tried replacing the `bunny.interactive = true;` to `img.eventMode = 'static'` but it gives me the same error, but at least the PixiJs warning is gone.

How I call the start event `img.on('pointerdown', this.onDragStart, img);`

And the other events:

```
this.app.stage.on('pointerup', this.onDragEnd);
this.app.stage.on('pointerupoutside', this.onDragEnd);
```

Why does it give me these errors when I've followed what is described on the example page? Perhaps I am just missing something simple but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

Doing this: `img.on('pointerdown', (event) => { console.log("test") });` gives the same error, so it is not the function that I am calling that is the issue.

Comment: Could you create a playground to recreate the issue? I created this https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/-yDkjdQvAEi48eTzRdNAc and I don't experience your described problem.

Comment: I've figured it out! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a vue issue.

I was creating a pixi application in the data function and then assigning it to a new pixi application with the actual config.

That it did not like. So i deleted it from the data function and just used a const and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to Vue, but to fix it, use:

```js
mounted() {
    this.app = markRaw(new PIXI.Application({ ... }))
}
```